# MySql stored procedure SET command -- when it errors

Tags: mysql, rdbms

After Googling for awhile I didn't see an answer.  Anyway I have a situation in a stored procedure where I do a set select like:

```
SET someVariable = (SELECT ...)
```

Anyway, due to some redundant records existing somewhere else in the system, this SELECT query used in the SET returns more than one row.  I'm guessing this will cause breakage or badness?  True, false?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot pass multiple records into scalar variable. Write the query correctly to return exact record, or insert data into another table.

Comment: This is what I did.  I was told this particular table did not have redundant entries and took that at face value.  That the column I needed was not unique is why I tracked this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. When assigning to a variable, the query must return a single row, containing a single column. You can also do it with this syntax:

```
SELECT someColumn INTO myVariable ... LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: And if it has two rows, is it a warning, an exception, will it crash the rest of my procedure?  Thanks.

Comment: Then MySQL will give an error (not sure which one, but maybe "Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row")